# Adding class and removing from others

Tags: jquery

I realise similar questions have been asked but I feel my setup is slightly different to the ones I have seen. I have the following markup:

```js
$("#oneLink").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#oneLinkText').toggleClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
});
 
$("#twoLink").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#twoLinkText').toggleClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
});
 
$("#threeLink").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#threeLinkText').toggleClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
});
```

```css
.text-area {
display: none;
}

.checked {
display: block;
}

#oneLinkText {
background-color: red;
}

#twoLinkText {
background-color: green;
}

#threeLinkText {
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-9">
            <div class="links-container">
              <a id="oneLink" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a id="twoLink" href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a id="threeLink" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-content-container col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div id="oneLinkText" class="text-area">
              <p>
                Some Text
              </p>
              <a class="button button-std" href="#">Text</a>
            </div>
            <div id="twoLinkText" class="text-area">
              <p>
                Some Text
              </p>
              <a class="button button-std" href="#">Text</a>
            </div>
            <div id="threeLinkText" class="text-area">
              <p>
                Some Text
              </p>
              <a class="button button-std" href="#">Text</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Now, the area where I am having an issue is making the click relate to the corresponding text area without the current duplication of code that I have. I can recognise this is highly inefficient. So for example, clicking on `#oneLink` displays `#oneLinkText` and removes the class from all other `.text-area`.

Is this type of cross-referencing possible without the duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the fact that your div ids are almost the same as the links:

```
$("a").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'Text').toggleClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
});
```

Comment: I will change the click listener to `$(".links-container a").click(...)` just to be more specific and don't capture the click on all the `anchor` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will be close enough. I have created a custom attribute to hold the target textarea ID and rest is done by jQuery. Let me know any questions or improvement needed.

```js
$(".aLink").on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let content = $(this).attr("data-content");
  $("#"+content).show();
  
  //hide other textarea
  $(".aLink").not(this).each(function(){
    let content = $(this).attr("data-content");
    $("#"+content).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.text-area {
display: none;
}

#oneLinkText {
background-color: red;
}

#twoLinkText {
background-color: green;
}

#threeLinkText {
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-9">
            <div class="links-container">
              <a class="aLink" data-content="oneLinkText" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="aLink" data-content="twoLinkText" href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a class="aLink" data-content="threeLinkText" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-content-container col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div id="oneLinkText" class="text-area">
              <p>
                Some Text
              </p>
              <a class="button button-std" href="#">Text</a>
            </div>
            <div id="twoLinkText" class="text-area">
              <p>
                Some Text
              </p>
              <a class="button button-std" href="#">Text</a>
            </div>
            <div id="threeLinkText" class="text-area">
              <p>
                Some Text
              </p>
              <a class="button button-std" href="#">Text</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple .. is to use same class and no need for id's .. you can just add your target div in the `href` attribute like this `<a class="showText" href="#oneLinkText">Link 1</a>`

```js
$(".showText").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $($(this).attr('href')).toggleClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
});
```

```css
.text-area {
display: none;
}

.checked {
display: block;
}

#oneLinkText {
background-color: red;
}

#twoLinkText {
background-color: green;
}

#threeLinkText {
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-9">
            <div class="links-container">
              <a class="showText" href="#oneLinkText">Link 1</a>
              <a class="showText" href="#twoLinkText">Link 2</a>
              <a class="showText" href="#threeLinkText">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-content-container col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div id="oneLinkText" class="text-area">
              <p>
                Some Text
              </p>
              <a class="button button-std" href="#">Text</a>
            </div>
            <div id="twoLinkText" class="text-area">
              <p>
                Some Text
              </p>
              <a class="button button-std" href="#">Text</a>
            </div>
            <div id="threeLinkText" class="text-area">
              <p>
                Some Text
              </p>
              <a class="button button-std" href="#">Text</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Additional:** if you need to show a specific text on load you can add `.eq(0).click()` `.eq(index)` index starts from 0 so the first text will show .. you can change 0 with 1 or 2 as you like .. see the next code

```js
$(".showText").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $($(this).attr('href')).toggleClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
}).eq(0).click();
```

```css
.text-area {
display: none;
}

.checked {
display: block;
}

#oneLinkText {
background-color: red;
}

#twoLinkText {
background-color: green;
}

#threeLinkText {
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-9">
            <div class="links-container">
              <a class="showText" href="#oneLinkText">Link 1</a>
              <a class="showText" href="#twoLinkText">Link 2</a>
              <a class="showText" href="#threeLinkText">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-content-container col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div id="oneLinkText" class="text-area">
              <p>
                Some Text
              </p>
              <a class="button button-std" href="#">Text</a>
            </div>
            <div id="twoLinkText" class="text-area">
              <p>
                Some Text
              </p>
              <a class="button button-std" href="#">Text</a>
            </div>
            <div id="threeLinkText" class="text-area">
              <p>
                Some Text
              </p>
              <a class="button button-std" href="#">Text</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it in case your links and divs are not related name-wise...

```
<div class="links-container">
              <a id="oneLink" data-target="#oneLinkText" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a id="twoLink" data-target="#twoLinkText" href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a id="threeLink" data-target="#threeLinkText" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>

$(".links-container a").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this.attr("data-target")).toggleClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
});
```